# RegEx to match a specific URL

Tags: .net, regex, pattern-matching

Old Working Pattern until the website changes how it host files.

```
http[s]?://[0-9a-z_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}[:0-9]*/([0-9a-z_./-])*[0-9a-z _.-](?:jpg|bmp|gif|png)+
```

I cant figure out how to write a valid regex to match a url pattern to pull images from a webpage.

The images strings I want to exact have this pattern:

```
images.domain.com/1/src/1333849327175.jpg
images.domain.com/2/src/2311487564321.png
images.domain.com/a/src/4568436431234.gif
images.domain.com/b/src/1234237456466.jpeg
images.domain.com/abc12/src/123456466.bmp
```

There are a lot of other images so I only want the ones that fit the pattern of images.domain.com

I just can't wrap my head around it! Tried this, but is there an easy way to test it?

```
images[0-9a-z_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}[:0-9]*/([0-9a-z_./-])*[0-9a-z _.-](?:jpg|bmp|gif|png)+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated/generic. Can't you just a specific one:

```
images\.domain\.com/[0-9a-z]+/src/[0-9]+\.(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png)
```

Here is a testing tool for .NET: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Cause I'm not sure what I'm doing so I'm programming extremely poorly. Could you remember a good read on how to learn more about RegEx?

Comment: Not really, but nothing beats just playing around with it.. What is your programming language?

Comment: c# is what I use the most, but work on some projects with vb.net

Comment: Well you can try this one: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx